# .NET Core IServiceScopeFactory.CreateScope() vs IServiceProvider.CreateScope() extension

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

My understanding is that when using the built in the dependency injection, a .NET Core console app will require you to create and manage all scopes yourself whereas a ASP.NET Core app will create and manage the `HttpRequest` scope by default through defined middleware(s).

With ASP.NET Core, you can optionally create and manage your own scopes that by calling `CreateScope()` for when you need services that live outside of a `HttpRequest`.

It is clear that calling `IServiceScopeFactory.CreateScope()` will create a new `IServiceScope` every time; however, does calling the `IServiceProvider.CreateScope()` extension method also create a new `IServiceScope` every time?

Basically, is there a meaningful difference between the following ways to create scope in both ASP.NET Core and .NET Core console apps:

```
public class Foo()
{
    public Foo(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        using(var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {   
            scope.ServiceProvider.GetServices<>();           
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Bar()
{
    public Bar(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        using(var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {   
            scope.ServiceProvider.GetServices<>();           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `IServiceProvider.CreateScope` will resolve `IServiceScopeFactory` and call `CreateScope` on it. So functionally both methods are identical, since one calls the other.

Comment: One line of code less yea. fwiw: You shouldn't ever have to inject neither scope factory nor service provider into your classes, except for a few rare infrastructure cases

Comment: That makes sense--to avoid the service locator pattern. In my case, the injection is for a `IHostedService/BackgroundService` which requires it's own scope separate from ASP.NET default. It would be just a single injection of the Service and all dependencies would be resolved from the registrations in `StartUp.cs`. I was struggling with injecting the `ApplicationDbContext` (scoped going into singleton = exception). Solved this by going with registring a singleton contextFactory. Any thoughts on that approach? Is it right?

Comment: CreateScope also is used for any root application containers like webhost service provider.Root application providers and all objects it create will live for the life of the application.If we resolve scoped or transient services from root container instance they will be created as singletons.Instead by using scope we can ensure that their intended lifetime is respected. Example
 var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
      {
         var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
         var ds = services.GetService<CatalogDataSource>();

Comment: @CK - I had a similar scenario - needed async Background service. So, I registered my service as HostedService and then used injected IServiceProvider to GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>(). Good article on a subject: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice

Comment: also for healthchecks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69002351/asp-net-core-healthchecks-concurrent-entity-framework-dbcontext-errors

Answer (score 101):

[CreateScope from IServiceProvider](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/94b9cc9ace032f838e068702cc70ce57cc883bc7/src/DI.Abstractions/ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.cs#L124) resolve `IServiceScopeFactory` and call `CreateScope()` on it:

```
public static IServiceScope CreateScope(this IServiceProvider provider)
{
    return provider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope();
}
```

So, as said @Evk

> functionally both methods are identical

`IServiceProvider` just wrapped call `CreateScope()` from `IServiceScopeFactory`

Answer (score 43):

From what I tested

In ASP.NET Core 5 the following code works:

```
[HttpGet("/Echo/{word}")]
public IActionResult EchoAndLog(string word, [FromServices] IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
{
    var ipAddress = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;

    // No need to wait for logging, just fire and forget
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);

        using (var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<LogDbContext>();

            var log = new ActivityLog
            {
                IpAddress = ipAddress,
                Endpoint = "Echo",
                Parameter = word
            };

            context.Add(log);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();                                        
        }
    });

    return Ok(word);
}
```

Now if you change the `IServiceScopeFactory`  to `IServiceProvider` it will NOT work:

```
[HttpGet("/Echo/{word}")]
public IActionResult EchoAndLog(string word, [FromServices] IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var ipAddress = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;

    // No need to wait for logging, just fire and forget
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);

        using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<LogDbContext>();

            var log = new ActivityLog
            {
                IpAddress = ipAddress,
                Endpoint = "Echo",
                Parameter = word
            };

            context.Add(log);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();                                        
        }
    });

    return Ok(word);
}
```

You will get the `System.ObjectDisposedException` exception:

> Cannot access a disposed object.
>
> Object name: 'IServiceProvider'.

Which tells me the `IServiceProvider` will live as long as the request's lifetime (scoped), but this is not the case with `IServiceScopeFactory`.

Comment: `IServiceProvider` is a scoped service, and `IServiceScopeFactory` is a singleton. I can imagine that before the code in `Task.Run` starts executing, the request finishes and the corresponding scope is destroyed, along with `IServiceProvider` instance passed as parameter. Leaving tasks executing in the background seems fishy.

Answer (score 10):

In short, `IServiceProvider.CreateScope()` and `IServiceScopeFactory.CreateScope()` are identical (in non-scoped context even instances of `IServiceProvider` and `IServiceScopeFactory` are identical).

#### But here is a little difference between these abstractions

`IServiceProvider`'s lifetime **can be** `Scoped`. But `IServiceScopeFactory`'s lifetime is always `Singleton`.

#### When `IServiceProvider` is scoped?

When we inject it into a scoped service or method. So, when we inject `IServiceProvider` into a controller for example, it is possible to resolve scoped dependencies without scope creating (because in this case scope is already created).

#### Example

So, in the example below you don't need to create scope to resolve (retrieve) a scoped service in any action of the controller:

```cs
public class SomeController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public SomeController(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public IActionResult SomeAction()
    {
        //Resolve a scoped service from IServiceProvider without creating a scope:
        var service = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ScopedService>();
        return Ok(service.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

But when we inject `IServiceProvider` into singleton it'll be a root provider (without ability to get scoped services). 
[Here is](https://github.com/rodion-m/AspNetCourse2022-1/tree/master/lessons/ServiceProviderChecks) I've prepared more examples.

Note that you should avoid using `IServiceProvider` or even `IServiceScopeFactory` because **they both implement an anti-pattern** that called [Service Locator](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).

Comment: @Connie King This should be marked as the answer. The difference metioned in this answer is not something that can be missed!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be interesting question. Also finding @Sasan is quite good and it really highlight few things and usage scenario.

I am taking @Sasan example code and providing few more details about behavior of those two.

Look at following two sample.

```
 Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);

        using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
```

and

```
 Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);

        using (var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
```

What is happening in sample that code is running without waiting for task completion. In this scenario

- Example with IServiceProvider gives error because serviceProvider that available in method using [FromServices] has lifetime of scope. In this case request. When controller method return serviceProvider object become disposable so exception is being caught.
- Now in this case if following scenario is there.

```
 Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
```

- In above case there is no error because as soon as task start it capture scope and that will be used but in case of delay by the time task wakeup again
  method return so object serviceProvider become disposed and it has no chance to create scope.
- In case IScopedServiceFactory, this is not the issue. Reason is this is Singleton so that object is there for lifetime of entire application so it will not dispose even method return.
  So for IScopedServiceFactory scenario wait before capture or after capture same things.

```
Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);

        using (var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
```

and

```
Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        using (var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
         await Task.Delay(1000);
```

Note:

- For IServiceProvider or IScopedServiceFactory when call CreateScope, there is no different as internally it call same method. That is highlighted earlier.
- Only difference is IServiceProvider and IScopedServiceFactory is lifetime, one is Scoped and another one is Singleton. It makes difference in few corner cases.